# Firebase hosting with reactjs cannot handle /redirect from third party authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I am new to reactjs and Firebase web hosting.

I am using Sketchfab OAuth2 for my web. So, I need to provide a redirect link to Sketchfab, e.g. https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/redirect

However, I am using `react-router` and no matter what pages I routed to, there is a '#' in the url, e.g. https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/#/login and https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/#/redirect. This makes me cannot get the OAuth token from Sketchfab because my url and the redirect url are not match.

I have requested to use https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/#/redirect as the redirect url. However, Sketchfab does not support having '#' in the redirect url.

Possible solution to this problem:

1. Find a way to remove the '#' from my url
2. Make use of firebase.json to rewrite the destination of all `**/redirect/**` source to the https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/#/redirect

For option 2, I don't know how to do this in reactjs since I only know how to rewrite the destination to a html file, e.g. /index.html

This is the theme I am using for my web: https://startreact.com/themes/ani-theme/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you might be using `HashRouter` instead of `Browser Router`. Using `HashRouter` controls the URI after the hash key, which can be useful if your static server that doesn't support single page apps (e.g. Github Pages). I'm pretty sure you can use `Browser Router` in Firebase, so in your Router component you have to import the right Router: `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'`.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using this theme https://startangular.com/product/ani-theme/. Can you teach me how to change it to use BrowserRouter?